# UWP/C# Issue passing a ColorPicker selection into a variable

Tags: c#, uwp

Im having difficulties with passing a Color from the ColorPicker into another sheet.
Im attempting to store the Brush as a variable so i can pass this variable into another sheet. 
As another person pointed out on my last post, every time i navigate away from a page, the data is cleared from the settings page and thus, there is no way for my "MainPage" to retrieve the brush.

**UseCase**:
Whenever I change the color on Settings Page tht should be reflected on my MainPage.

Im not sure how to implement this at all and the documentation on this is mainly only for using it locally.

I have the following event trigger on ColorChange within thge Settings_Page.xaml:

```
private void TextColourPicker_ColorChanged(ColorPicker sender, ColorChangedEventArgs args)
    {

    }
```

I was thinking of doing something like i had to do with one of my GlobalVariables. This involved a GlobalVariables_PropertyChanged event. The Colour event seems different though.

I have created a Static Class within my GlobalVariableStorage Class as follows:

```
  public static class ColourSelections
    {
        private static Brush _TextColour;
        public static Brush TextColour
        {
            get { return _TextColour; }
            set { _TextColour = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
        }
```

I have no idea if this is right or if it helps at all.

My hope was to assign the selected colour to the GlobalVariables text colour brush. 
If anyone has any better execution methods for this, please let me know.

I am in the process of trying to work in an MVVM approach but adjusting my code as I go and learn.

I apologise for my vagueness and lack of understanding. Passing brush information between sheets is new to me and im just not sure how to approach it.

**Edit:**

I have added the following.

On my Settings_Page.xaml.cs:

```
private void TextColourPicker_ColorChanged(ColorPicker sender, ColorChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            SolidColorBrush TextColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(TextColourPicker.Color);
            ColourSelections.TextColour = TextColorBrush;
        }
```

This writes to the following class within the GlobalVariableStorage.cs:

```
public static class ColourSelections
    {
        private static Brush _TextColour;
        public static Brush TextColour
        {
            get { return _TextColour; }
            set { _TextColour = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }           
        }      

        public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private static void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "") =>
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

What i now need to do is:

Read the TextColour variable back into Mainpage. The issue is, the thing im trying to change is the NavigationViewItem "Foreground" Colour.

Comment: have you tried passing the variable from SettingsPage to MainPage?

Comment: yes the data on settings page is removed when u navigated away from it, but if you pass a variable as a parameter to another page that specific variable is not removed from memory and you can succesfully use it on next page. Please let me know if you tried this then what problems you had in that?

Comment: Hi Touseefbsb, just writing up a little bit of code to help explain this. Im passing a variable into the GlobalVariablesStorage class currently. I believe im stuck on reading it back in. Essentially, it changes the NavigationText a different colour

Comment: if your project is not too complicated , I suggest upload it to a github repo and share it with us, I will try to solve it on my end and then share the solution with you.

Comment: ^ill do this, please not it does require the insider build of Windows to compile. Im using a lot of features only available on the insider build. Specific version is 17723

Comment: btw I can see that you are doing it pretty much the correct way, whenever the static property changes it should be reflected on your navigationview color, considering the binding is oneway

Comment: are you also using the preview sdk as minimum project target?

Comment: yea, min is 17723 as well. It uses the pre-release NuGet Packages as too which may be an issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180155/discussion-between-touseefbsb-and-batteredburrito).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it the right way using the **static** class, whenever the color is changed you can assign the value of new color to the variable within your static class and to read it on **MainPage** just override the **OnNavigatedTo** method on MainPage and assign the color value to each of your **NavigationViewItems** there.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(object sender, object args)
{
    if(ColourSelections.TextColor != null)
    {
        //considering NavigationItem1 is the x:Name of your first NavigtionViewItem.
        NavigationItem1.Foreground = ColourSelections.TextColor;
    }
}
```

Note : Make sure the type of TextColor is **SolidColorBrush** because that is the type of Foreground as well.